# tomcat7, spring 3.0.5, errors, contexts

Tags: spring, tomcat7

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader, in the event of an exception, does:

```
servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, ex);
```

which looks quite useful, except the servlet context object it is making this call on is not connected, in any way that I can find, to the return value from `Tomcat.addWebapp`. So when I go looking for this attribute to see whether the startup worked right, I'm thwarted.

Is there a way to connect these two contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat's documentation says you can get `ServletContext` from web-app's `Context`:

```
ServletContext getServletContext()
```

See [JavaDoc on Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Context.html).